# Getting Unknown MySQL Error while executing queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, rmysql

Configurations:

```
R version: 3.6.3
Aurora MySQL Cluster: 5.7
Library: RMySQL
```

Dbconnect Method

```
con <- dbConnect(
      RMySQL::MySQL(),
      dbname = dbName,
      host = "127.0.0.1",
      user = user,
      port = port,
      password = pass
    )
```

Connecting to the Aurora DB using SSH:

```
ssh -N -L <local_port>:<amazon_rds_cluster_url>:<sql_port> -i <pem_file> ubuntu@<ip>
```

Query and result:

```
query <- "SELECT column_name FROM table_name;"
result <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

When I am calling the query directly, it is executed as intended.
When I am calling it from a method in a package, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown MySQL error
```

I am not sure why I am seeing the error.

EDIT:

```
method <- function(con, query) {
    output <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
    return(output)
}

result <- package::method(con, query)
```

Comment: Are you able to run the query directly in database using tool like MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin or SQLyog? If you can, does it return any result or is it returning error?

Comment: Yes. I use MySQL workbench and am able to run queries there.

Comment: Do you have any indication that the database is connected when you run the code?

Comment: Yes. I use a tryCatch to check that the db connection is made and then only run the code.

Comment: _"When I am calling it from a method in a package"_  can you please specify the method?

Comment: Please refer to the edit part in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I removed some parameters from you code.

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='password', dbname='my_database', host='localhost')
```

Comment: I tried with it. But still the query is not executing.